# How to browse SO data dump?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, data-dump

I'm looking for a way to let my students browse *StackOverflow*, *Superuser* and other *StackExchange* sites from within our inner network (internet connection is not an option).

I'm currently downloading [*StackExchange data dump*](http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss), when the final target is to let my students open it inside our inner network using `http://stackoverflow/` or similar.

(We did the same thing with wikipedia, and it worked wonderfully.)

**Question is** - How do I create a real mirror out of the dump? Is that even the right way to do this?
 If it's not, is there a way to create a mirror of StackOverflow inside my inner network (other than using a spider/crawler to cache HTML pages)?

(Maybe the Data Explorer can help me read these XMLs somehow?)

Comment: The data dump contains only public data. And you don't have an logic coming with it.

Comment: I see.. Do you know an easy way to cache and mirror SO? I think that would help not only me, but many other academic places that don't have direct internet connection

Comment: You can't just copy a dynamic website like SO. You don't have access to the server side logic which is huge.

Comment: Point is, I don't even need the server side logic (posting comments, asking questions, earning badges etc.) - I just need the information in some readable format. On the other hand, I don't have the time nor the resources to write a view over the XML files - and a mirror would solve it pretty easily...

Comment: This looks hopeful: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-da/1247#1247 Found with the google query "stack exchange data dump viewer" (no qoutes)

Comment: @juergend, What does  "don't have an logic coming with it" mean?

Comment: @Pacerier: It means you only get the pure data. But not the code that builds the website.

Comment: @juergend, Uhm, isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having some research done, I found that amazing program called **[Stackdump](https://stackapps.com/questions/3610/stackdump-an-offline-browser-for-stackexchange-sites)**.

I deployed it on my ubuntu, followed the README and ran it on `diy.stackoverflow.com`, it worked just as expected (had to fix a typo in the script - Comments.xml instead of comments.xml, etc.)

To whom of you that wants to deploy a web server for browsing *StackExchange* data offline - it seems like the perfect solution. You are more than welcome to ask me for any further instructions :)

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick search and found something that looks like a good starting point:
[StackExchange Data Dump Viewer - A Desktop Tool for Viewing the StackExchange Data Dumps](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-da/1247#1247)

Found with the google query `stack exchange data dump viewer`

Comment: Found this with the google query `stack exchange data dump viewer`

Answer (score 0):

Dash announced that they use the Stack Overflow data dump to view SO offline.

- https://blog.kapeli.com/dash-2-dot-1